# ckeditor 4.5.3 installation fails

Tags: installation, ckeditor

So, trying to upgrade to CKEditor 4.5.3 (from 4.4.7.4). I "built" my package, including some plugins that we are using, did the download... copied up the code. But when I try to open up a page with CKEditor on it, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
```

The problem comes down to this reference:

```
attributes:("aria-label":a.lang.contextmenu.options
```

That's in Chrome. In firefox, it just tells me that a.lang.contextmenu is undefined.

This is a pretty stock installation. I have tried removing my configurations, and have added "config.language = 'en';" in case
it was defaulting wrong. But no love. Any ideas?

thanks,
Andy

Comment: You can usually see these errors if cache wasn't cleared.

Comment: I read that... using Chrome, I'm selecting the "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" option. Ok... quitting the browser altogether and starting it back up worked. Weird. THanks.

Comment: It is now 2018 already - 3 years later!!?? And I have exactly this same problem. I am concerned about CKEditor arbitrarily failing on my production server. I don't want to be telling people to refresh their cache so that my application works...?

Comment: It seems the problem is due to incorrect language detection: https://csharpin.blogspot.com/2011/08/ckeditor-mlangcontextmenu-is-undefined.html